# React.js consume java rest services

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React.js and I would like to know how to consume a java ee rest service from react.js.
I mean, what tools I must to learn/use in order to consume a java ee rest service (GET, POST, PUT, etc) from react.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React itself doesn't prescribe how to interact with the traditional "Model" part of MVC paradigms. However most React applications use some flavor of a Flux architecture for server interactions.

One Flux implementation in particular that has significant traction is [Redux](http://redux.js.org/), and there is a [redux-crud](https://github.com/Versent/redux-crud) module that works with Redux to provide actions-creators for REST interactions. However this digs pretty deep into React/Flux/Redux territory, so it might be conceptually challenging for a beginner.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have created a little crud application with a java ee rest service, and now I want to do the same using react.js. I will check the Redux implementation. Also I saw in the react.js web page, a tutorial that uses jquery ($.ajax call) to make a request to the server, do you think that the path to follow is a flux architecture? or the jquery ajax call will by also fine? Thanks

Comment: The $ajax within the componentDidMount or componentWillMount methods is a simple way to get started, and become familiar with the basic pattern.  Though my experience is that it becomes very complicated to manage as the application grows.  Which will inevitably lead to flux.